# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova app wont build and hangs

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'd done a clean install of windows 8.1, downloaded VS 2015 community update 1. (i've also tried this with VS 2015 Enterprise Edition) I then create a new javascript cordova app. Everything loads up fine. as soon as i start building the project the build process just hangs for many hours.

There are no build errors at all and nothing seems to end. I need to end VS using the task manager to close the project to test again.

This is have tried

1: clearing the cordova cache

2.Running the dependancy checker which returns that everything is ok.

3. Renaming the CoreCon folder to something else
4. Checked to see if all the packages are installed in the VS installer.

Once i create a new cordova project then build i get this in the output and it will just hang there for days!!

```
1>Target "InstallMDA" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" from project "c:\users\clzby\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7\BlankCordovaApp7.jsproj" (target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" depends on it):
1>       Using "RunMdaInstall" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>       Task "RunMdaInstall"
```

Im now totally lost, i dont understand as to why i install a new product and the build does not work.. Im i missing something?

---

updates

My current version of node is 
4.1.2

current version of cordova is
5.4.1

here is also a link to some microsoft issues

http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/known-issues-ripple-cordova/#strongbuild-hangs-or-does-not-execute-when-building-for-ios-with-cordova-lt-533-and-nodejs-400strong

but im still have the same issue where nothing is building in a cordova javascript or typescript project

here is a diagnostic output

```
1>Target "InstallMDA: (TargetId:11)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets" from project "c:\users\clzby\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp15\BlankCordovaApp15\BlankCordovaApp15.jsproj" (target "EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion" depends on it):
1>                   Using "RunMdaInstall" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.dll".
1>                   Task "RunMdaInstall" (TaskId:10)
1>                     Task Parameter:MdaVsixDir=E:\New folder\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools (TaskId:10)
1>                     Task Parameter:NodeInstallPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs (TaskId:10)
1>                     Task Parameter:NpmInstallDir=C:\Users\Clzby\AppData\Roaming\npm (TaskId:10)
1>                     Task Parameter:LangName=en-US (TaskId:10)
1>                     Task Parameter:ProjectDir=. (TaskId:10)
1>                     Task Parameter:Configuration=Debug (TaskId:10)
1>                     Task Parameter:PackageName=vs-tac (TaskId:10)
1>                     Task Parameter:BuildVerbosity=Diagnostic (TaskId:10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are targeting Cordova 5.4.1. There are numerous incompatibilities and problems with 5.4 with both Visual Studio and Windows. Please change your target CLI to 5.3.3.

Our next update will include support for 5.4.1, but Update 4 will not work with it.

(Disclosure: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio)

Comment: thankyou for your reply. i updated node to the latest version, then i done a repair on Visual Studio and now its working even though im using i checked cordova -v and using 5.4.1 but in the platforms section of the config.xml i changed that to 5.3.3 and now its working , 1 weeks worth of testing,, but thanks again. I think a document needs to be written about this to help others. thx